# dynamically change height attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently re-sizing a DIV class based on the users window size / resolution - I tested it and once I re-size my browser window to below 1024 x 768 the css attribute changes properly. The problem is now, when I maximize the window the attribute stays with the new properties (400 / 380). Is there a way to have it reset once my resolution goes back to over 1024 x 768?

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var h = $(window).height();
        var w = $(window).width();
        $("#scrollbar1").css('height',(h < 1024 || w < 768) ? 400 : 380);
    });
});
```

Some advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: probably mean `(w < 1024 || h < 768)`?

Comment: From memory (which is why I'm making this a comment rather than an answer) some browsers - _I'm looking at you IE6_ - don't trigger the resize event when you maximize or restore. I vaguely recall that we had to choose between either setting the element size once on load and not worrying if the user resized after that, or a clunky workaround based on a `setInterval` that compared the current size with the previously saved size every 10ms (or whatever interval suits). Of course with IE6 we couldn't make it work with just CSS...

Comment: I tried to add `$("#scrollbar1").css('height',(h > 1024 || w > 768) ? 650 : 420);` unfortunately that does not help. Any ideas on how I can solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your screen-resolution is height:768 * width:1024 :

First see the comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/222714/mdmullinax , you currently detect if the width is < 768 or height is < 1024 , you should switch this.

Then: you cant rely on the fact that a maximized browser-window will have a inner size similar to the screen-size.

width()/height() will return the size of the viewport, so when the window is maximized there still may be some bars on the desktop (and the browsers bars like toolbar, adressbar etc. too) that let the browser-windows size differ from the screen-size)